# Printing in ie11 On landscape mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to print an HTML page in landscape mode on ie 11. I tried the following CSS code and not working

1

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page
{
    size: 11in 8.5in;
}
</style>
```

2

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page
{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
```

3

```
@media print {
    @page {
        /*IE Landscape fix*/
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=3);
    }
}
```

4

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page
{ 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%; 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=3);
} 
</style>
```

Comment: have you tried: `@media print{@page {size: landscape}}` ?

Comment: yes i tried it but not worked

Answer (score 1):

You have to set html/css this way:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
 @page { size: landscape; }
</style>
```

in your html or

```
@media print{@page {size: landscape}}
```

in your css